# Integrate a USB connected scale to a web app with java or some other framework?

Tags: java, web, usb, integration

I am trying to integrate any kind of a postage scale with my web app so that I can get the current weight from my application. Most computer connected scales seem to use USB but I am not finding anything promising for web integration.
Any advice is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

https://github.com/JaggedJax/CIO_Scale

You probably want a Java Applet though as there is no way for JS to access the USB devices on your host machine.